# could not find function "ggplot"?

Tags: ggplot2

I am having this problem ***could not find function "ggplot"***     even after running:

install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

Please help me.

I am expecting to have a scatter plot instead I am keep getting this error:

could not find function "ggplot"

Comment: When you ran `install.packages("ggplot2")` did the installation complete without errors? If not, can you share what the errors were?